# Enable Azure Availability tests access to API

Tags: azure, api, azure-application-insights

I have an API deployed to Azure as a WebApp. I also have availability tests from AppInsights, that simply call a URL of that API to check the response. All worked fine until I added a few of IP address restrictions in web app to limit the inbound access to the API. I then googled and found [an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses) where AppInsight IPs are listed that are used for availability tests. I only selected the IPs from North and West Europe as my availability test has been configured to run from those two locations only.

Now availability test responds with 403 - Forbidden until I remove all IP restrictions. After that - HTTP200.

Question - how to properly enable access from Azure AppInsights availability tests to my API?

P.S. Both AI and API are within the same Azure resource group.

Comment: UPDATE: when I added logs to detect the incoming IPs, found out that Azure uses two more unlisted IPs. Once I added them into Access Restrictions, all started working fine. Till Sunday morning, when new IP from West Europe seems have changed. WTH?

Comment: Could you find any solution?